# Combination of two arrays

Tags: c#, arrays

I have a integer array that shows the nodes of a path : {1,2,3,4,5}
1 --> 2 --> 3 --> 4 --> 5

But some nodes of this path can be optional. 
For example node 4 is optional.
So, I can use this path 1 --> 2 --> 3 --> 4 --> 5 
or this path 1 --> 2 --> 3 --> 5 to reach my destination.

I want to produce all path combinations.
//ProduceCombinations(int[] path,int[] possibleNodes)

### **{1*,2,3,4*,5*}**

12345
-2345
123-5
-23-5
1234-
-234-
123--
-23--
12345
-2345
123-5
-23-5
1234-
-234-
123--
-23--

Comment: What is the result type?

Comment: result type can be List of arrays or 2D array.

Comment: Can you add what you've tried already to your question, so that we can maybe build upon that rather than completely changing your approach.

Comment: You want an algorithm? Stackoverflow is not a code service site. Show what you tried. Explain the problem and we can try and help you correct it. Also, please read [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [Take The Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to better understand how this site works

Comment: The results are repeated. You should post some code (and some more notes) that explain the procedure.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int[] pathNodes = new int[] {1,2,3,4,5};
            int[] optionalNodes = new int[] { 1, 4, 5 };

            List<int[]> combies = ProduceCombinations(pathNodes, optionalNodes);

        }

        public static List<int[]> ProduceCombinations(int[] PathNodes, int[] OptionalNodes)
        {
            List<int[]> results = new List<int[]>();
            results.Add((int[])PathNodes.Clone());
            int index = 0;
            for (int j = 0; j < OptionalNodes.Length; j++)
            {
                while (PathNodes[index] < OptionalNodes[j]) index++;

                int lenght = results.Count;
                for(int i = 0; i < lenght; i++)
                {
                    var newSol = (int[])results[i].Clone();
                    newSol[index] = 0;
                    results.Add(newSol);
                }
            }

            return results;
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for help Aldert, your logic is working for ordered arrays.